# Could not load module: CTLS

Tags: ios, swift

I import JWT(using .Package(url:"https ://github.com/vapor/jwt.git", majorVersion: 1))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4o3n.jpg)

The project can build and run. But when I look into CTLS, the Xcode shows "Could not load module: CTLS". I don't know why.

At the same time, the JWT I create seems not right. Here is my codes:

```
import JWT
import Vapor

get("token") { req in
let algValue = StructuredData.string("ES256")
let kidValue = StructuredData.string("CapExedKid")
let headerData = StructuredData.object(["alg":algValue,"kid":kidValue])
let header = JSON.init(headerData)
let issValue = StructuredData.string("CapExdTeam")
let sec = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
let iatValue = StructuredData.number(StructuredData.Number(sec))
let expValue = StructuredData.number(StructuredData.Number(sec+1000000))
let claimsData = StructuredData.object(["iss":issValue,"iat":iatValue,"exp":expValue])
let claims = JSON.init(claimsData)
let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/aamac/Desktop/HelloWorld/AuthKey_demoKey.p8")
let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: url)
let signer = ES256.init(key: data.makeBytes())
let jwt = try JWT.init(headers: header, payload: claims, signer: signer)
let token = try jwt.createToken() 
return token }
```

I use the token to do the authenticate requests as Apple Music API says, I got a http status code 500.. 
I enter this in terminal:
curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer [developer token]' "https ://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/songs/203709340"
and got 500..

But I use a Python library to get the token and do the request in terminal, it works, so I doubt that the JWT in swift have some kind of problem...Can anyone tell me??

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem (https://github.com/vapor/jwt/issues/47). What worked for me was using `data.bytes.base64Decoded` instead of `data.makeBytes()` when initializing the signer.

Comment: It seems not work for me.. Do you read the .p8 file as I do? Do you just paste the private key as a String and use it as a key? Was your signer ES256, or RS256 as the link you metioned? Thank you for your help~

Comment: I used the private key as a string (mine was RS256 though).